# Nextjs 13 able to fetch and scrape a webpage when running the server locally, but when the application is deployed on Vercel, the fetching fails

Tags: fetch-api, jsdom, next.js13

Here's the GET function that is scraping the website

```
export async function GET(req) {
  const itemNumber = req.url.split("scrape_costco/")[1];
  console.log("Item #: ", itemNumber);
  try {
    console.log("scraping costco")
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://www.costco.com/CatalogSearch?dept=All&keyword=${itemNumber}`
    );
    // log the response url
    console.log(res.url);
    // console.log(res.headers)
    console.log(req.headers)
    const html = await res.text();
    const dom = new JSDOM(html);
    const document = dom.window.document;
    const productName = document.querySelector(".description a")?.textContent;
    console.log(productName);
    if (!productName) throw new Error("Product not found");
    return NextResponse.json(productName.trim());
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(console.error(error));
  }
}
```

Running the server locally returns the product name just fine but once i deploy to vercel the function fails to run. On the backend it I get a status code 500 and on client side its a 504 code and  I also get this error

```
488-8986c8e24f6e0c60.js:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'A', "An error o"... is not valid JSON
```

I've tried adding in headers manually and I also tried creating an express app to handle the backend but nothing worked

Comment: Have you verified whether the URL you are scraping from is blocking non residential IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Vercel timeout functions are being triggered before fetch, Try running it via a cron job. Check below document regarding the vercel timeout limits.

https://vercel.com/changelog/serverless-functions-can-now-run-up-to-5-minutes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).